# When you hand over something banned before getting on a plane, what verb should you use?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I feel a bit embarrassed to ask this but when you hand over something banned before getting on a plane, what verb should you use? Like, 'surrender' or 'give up'? And, speaking of it, what do you call those places at airports where your luggage is scanned, you're frisked down, etc.?

Comment: People commonly talk about **going through security** at airports, where items that are not permitted are confiscated. I don't know of a specific word for handing an item over. You could use **surrender** or **hand over**

Comment: Those who feel the restrictions are onerous and often arbitrary would favor the term **confiscate**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Surrendered** is a good option but may also convey that the action was taken with some hesitation.

> She **surrendered** the bottle of wine to the agent, displeased that customs cared about such a frivolous item.

If you have the flexibility, I would change the subject of your sentence.

> The TSA agent **confiscated** the nail clippers I had forgotten in my bag.

[*Confiscate*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confiscate): appropriated by the government, forfeited

As for the place, the TSA calls it [Security Screening](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening), but just **security** is understandable enough in context.

> I can accompany you as far as **security**, but then I will have to say goodbye.

Comment: **Surrender** is a good choice because it's one the TSA uses themselves: ["The final option is to voluntarily surrender (the item) to TSA."](https://www.tsa.gov/news/press/releases/2020/01/17/bradley-international-airport-makes-tsas-top-10-list-most-unusual)

Comment: To communicate that it was voluntary, *relinquish* can be used.

Comment: @LawrenceC I considered it, but Longman says it means "to let someone else have your position, power, or rights", not, I presumed, physical items (https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/relinquish)

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev You can certainly relinquish a physical item; I am not sure why Longman implies it can only be a position, power, or rights when [other dictionaries do not say that](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relinquish).  But *relinquish* is a very formal-sounding word, so it is usually used in more "formal" contexts.